# Will the application review the auto renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I'm developing an application that looks like a dialogue with another person. Some dialog branches are paid and are available only when the subscription is activated. When user click on this thread, we ask that him purchase it. When a person activates a subscription, he also has access to some paid video, audio, and a restriction on viewing the news section. We would like to use the Autorenewable subscription with a plan for a month. But will our application go through the review? maybe there are still some approaches to enable the user to activate auto-subscriptions to our application.
Thank you in advance for your cooperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be an ok use of IAP, however reviewers can act randomly so you may get a different result.

I would make sure that when a user encounters a path that is premium, you don't just initiate an in-app-purchase but you present the user with a "paywall", a screen that says the content is for purchase and show them the price and allow them to purchase. If you are too aggressive, Apple may reject your application.